# How to save subplot as PDF using FPDF and Streamlit

Tags: matplotlib, streamlit, pyfpdf

I have a subplot that I want to save in a PDF. I am trying to do this inside a Streamlit app and to create the PDF I am using FPDF library.
The subplot is working without any problems. The problem is that I can't save it as PDF because an error is shown saying that the figure that I want to save is not defined.
This is how I created the figure containing the subplot:

```
fig1, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

hip_angle, _, _ = angle_calculation(merged)
hip_angle_2, _, _ = angle_calculation(merged_2)

sub_plotting(freq_left, hip_angle_2, 'Hip angle - Left leg', ax1)
sub_plotting(freq_right, hip_angle, 'Hip angle - Right leg', ax2)
ax1.set_xlabel('Gait phase %')
ax2.set_xlabel('Gait phase %')
ax1.set_ylabel('Angle (degrees)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Angle (degrees)')
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 110, step=10))
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 110, step=10))
ax1.set_ylim([-20, 50])
ax2.set_ylim([-20, 50])

ax1.set_aspect('auto')
ax2.set_aspect('auto')

fig1.set_figheight(8)
fig1.set_figwidth(18)
st.pyplot(fig1)

# Here I am just creating a button to download the figure

fig = 'Hip angle.png'
plt.savefig(fig)
with open(fig, "rb") as f:
    btn = st.download_button(
        label="Descarregar imagem",
        data=f,
        file_name=fig,
        mime="image/png")
```

This is what I am using to try to save the figure in the PDF.

```
checkbox = st.checkbox('Name', value='')
if checkbox:
    name = st.text_input('Nome do utente', value=' ')

    st.download_button(
        label="Descarregar relatório",
        data=create_pdf(fig1),
        file_name="Relatório.pdf",
        mime="application/pdf",
    )
```

As I mentioned, there's an error saying that the `fig1` is not defined.
This is the function that I am using to create the PDF template.

```
def create_pdf(figure1):

    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()

    figure = io.BytesIO()
    figure1.savefig(figure, format="png")
    saved_fig = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

    with open(f"{saved_fig.name}.png", 'wb') as sf:
        sf.write(figure.getvalue())

    pdf.set_xy(30, 50)
    pdf.image(figure1, w=140, h=110)
    figure.close()

    return bytes(pdf.output())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified code that works with pdf download. We create the pdf file first based on png file. Once created we use it for download.

###### Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st 
from fpdf import FPDF


def create_pdf(img_fn, pdf_fn):
    """
    Create pdf written to pdf_fn with the image file img_fn.
    """
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()

    # Save to pdf
    pdf.set_xy(30, 50)
    pdf.image(img_fn, w=140, h=110)
    pdf.output(pdf_fn)


def main():
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    y = [1, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8]

    fig1, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

    ax1.plot(x, y)
    ax2.scatter(x, y)

    st.pyplot(fig1)

    # Save to png
    img_fn = 'Hip angle.png'
    fig1.savefig(img_fn)

    # Prepare file for download.
    dfn = 'angle.png'
    with open(img_fn, "rb") as f:
        st.download_button(
            label="Descarregar imagem",
            data=f,
            file_name=dfn,
            mime="image/png")

    # pdf download
    checkbox = st.checkbox('Name', value='')
    if checkbox:
        pdf_fn = 'mypdf.pdf'
        create_pdf(img_fn, pdf_fn)

        with open(pdf_fn, 'rb') as h_pdf:
            st.download_button(
                label="Descarregar relatório",
                data=h_pdf,
                file_name="Relatório.pdf",
                mime="application/pdf",
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

###### Output

[image]

###### Downloaded png output:

[image]

###### Downloaded pdf output

[image]